# Calling click from keydown, but getting the correct checkbox checked property

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This isn't a jQuery only question as it has to do with events and order of operation.  Consider the following code, which is based on jQuery multiSelect plugin (please post citation if you can find it):

#### [Fiddle with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/QJsPc/)

```
var debug     = $('#debug');
var updateLog = function (msg){
    debug.prepend(msg + '\n');
};

var title     = $('#title').focus();
var container = $('#container');

title.keydown(function(e){
   // up or down arrows
   if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 38) {
    
      var labels  = container.find('label');
      var idx_old = labels.index(labels.filter('.hover'));
      var idx_new = -1;
    
      if (idx_old < 0) {
         container.find('label:first').addClass('hover');
      } else if (e.keyCode == 40 && idx_old < labels.length - 1) {
         idx_new = idx_old + 1;
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38 && idx_old > 0) {
         idx_new = idx_old - 1;
      }
    
      if (idx_new >= 0) {
         jQuery(labels.get(idx_old)).removeClass('hover');
         jQuery(labels.get(idx_new)).addClass('hover');
      }
    
      return false;
   }
    
   // space/return buttons
   if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32) {
      var input_obj = container.find('label.hover input:checkbox');
      input_obj.click();          
      return false;
   }
});


// When the input is triggered with mouse
container
    .find('input:checkbox')
    .click(function(){
       var cb    = $(this);
       var class = "checked";
    
       if (cb.prop(class)){
           cb.parent('label').addClass(class);
       } else {
           cb.parent('label').removeClass(class);
       }
    
       updateLog( cb.closest('label').text().split(/[\s\n]+/).join(' ') + ': '
                + this.checked + ' , '
                + cb.prop(class));
        
       title.focus();
    })
;
```

Notice the difference in the checkbox value for when you click directly on the checkbox, versus when you select the checkbox with the space/enter key.  I believe this is because it's calling `click` during the `keydown` event, so the value of the checkbox is not yet changed; whereas if you actually click the input, the `mouseup` event occurs before the `click` (?), so the setting is applied.

The multiselect plugin does not call the click event, it has almost duplicate code.  I'm curious if it would be better to pass a parameter to the click event (or use a global) to detect if it issued by the keyboard or mouse, or if it is better to just do what the plugin did and have the code inside the `keydown` function.

Obviously, if the log were after the `click()` runs, the `keydown` would return trues, but there are things that happen inside of click that are based on the input's checked status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed it to use the change event instead of the click event for the checkboxes
http://jsfiddle.net/QJsPc/4/

Comment: Unfortunately, `change` doesn't seem to work correctly for IE7

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/QJsPc/10/ - I need to spend time debugging, because it doesn't even display the log during the first round of selecting with the spacebar/enter key

Comment: Change event worked, but I had to use the [blur/focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664771/ie7-change-event-not-being-triggered) in the keydown to make everything run smoothe for IE7