# IE7 change event not being triggered

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

**Am I doing something wrong? Why isn't the *`click`* event registering on the first keydown?**

http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/VJ5CX/

In the example,

1. Click the "Menu" to make sure it has focus
2. Use the arrow keys (up/down) to highlight an option
3. Use the spacebar to select the option

*Notice how the change() event is not being called.  Use the spacebar again to select the same option and notice it is working as it should.*

---

#### I've tried:

- using the blur/focus according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875236/overriding-check-box-in-javascript-with-jquery/2876016#2876016), but haven't had any luck
- setting the checked attribute to false, to make sure the change event is triggered

#### Interesting Findings:

- There isn't a problem when using a mouse (it triggers the change event on the first time, as expected)
- The problem still occurs for the keydown, even after selecting with the mouse (run, click an option, hover to the option and use the keyboard).

#### Expected Results:

- Using keyboard navigation (up/down arrows) and selecting with the spacebar, should trigger both the "keydown" and "click" log.  It doesn't work on the initial keydown, but does every subsequent time.  *(Check Firefox for a working example)*

Comment: IE7 was superseded by Internet Explorer 8 in March 2009.

Comment: Interesting (and well formatted!) analysis, but what is your actual question?

Comment: Tomalak: haha, how do I get it to work?  IE7 is still used by customers.

Comment: You forgot to define "work". State the desired behaviour.

Comment: Thank you Tomalak, I updated the question with the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, good to see you around, one of the answers in the [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875236/overriding-check-box-in-javascript-with-jquery/2876016#2876016), was right, however I thought I could do an initial blur/focus, I seemed to have needed to include it in each keydown event.  -- thx for considering this question, vol7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using blur/focus on the initial load.  Apparently I needed the blur/focus inside the keydown event:

```
if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32) {
   var cb = container.find('label.x-hover input:checkbox');

   cb.blur();             // <-- added
   cb.focus();            // <-- added
   cb.click();  
   updateLog('keydown');
   oTitle.focus();      
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. It happened with me as well. But i tried this, it helped. I am not sure whether this will work or not.

```
container
.find('input[type="checkbox"]')
.change(function(){
   var cb     = $(this);
   var sClass = "checked";

   if (cb.prop(sClass)) { 
       cb.parent('label').addClass(sClass); 
   } else { 
       cb.parent('label').removeClass(sClass); 
   }
   updateLog('click');        
   oTitle.focus();
})
```

;

Comment: I just gave it a shot, no luck.  It's interesting because it doesn't work on the first keydown, but works on every subsequent.  It doesn't matter if I use the mouse first, or not.